# CSS working in jsfiddle but not on my local server?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have recently started a project, just making a makeshift website thing for my digital class. I have made buttons with CSS but for some reason only one of the buttons is styled. I have set up the classes properly and the buttons even work fine in jsfiddle, just not on my website?

When i put it in jsfiddle it worked properly for both buttons

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 8);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(146, 255, 119);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px green;
  border-radius: 40%;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(123, 255, 0);
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform: scale(1.2) rotateZ(-10deg);
}
.button2 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(146, 255, 119);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px green;
  border-radius: 40%;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
.button2:hover {
  background-color: rgb(123, 255, 0);
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform: scale(1.2) rotateZ(10deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="button button1" style= "position: absolute; left: 28%; top: 207px;">SALES</button>
<button class="button button2" style= "position: absolute; left: 66.5%; top: 207px;">OTHER</button>
```

Both buttons should be styled but the classes are not working

Comment: how's the code on your local?

Comment: your code seems fine. if you are using external css please make sure your path is correct.